# Spring Data Mongo lazy loading

Tags: java, mongodb, lazy-loading, spring-data-mongodb, dbref

I'm trying to use Spring Data Mongo's `@DBRef(lazy = true)` feature for lazy loading of an association but it doesn't seem to work. Even though it loads the `Mainobject` with an empty `ReferencedObject`, inside the reference object there is a `CGLIB$CALLBACK_0` proxy object that has the association already loaded. Doesn't this beat the concept of lazy loading? Also, when I return the object to the client it returns the association twice:

```
mainObject: {
  field: value
  reference: { //same object
    refField: refValue
  },
  target: { //same object
    refField: refValue
  }
}
```

Isn't the goal for the lazy association to only fetch the object after some method call (like `getRefObject()` for example)? Also I'm failing to see how I can access the fetched object from its proxy once it is loaded since it is a private property and it doesn't have accessors...

Comment: please also add the according java sources and note that eg. using a lazy `DBRef` property as a constructor argument may force eager loading.

Comment: As I'm having he same problem,  was wondering if you had a workaround on it. All my Spring data documents are eagerly loaded even if they are marked lazy = true. The hole structure of parent-children objects is loaded out of my REST controller.

Comment: Nope we didn't solve it. I'm not sure if my debugger was causing the lazy loading when I was trying to access the object to watch its value but regardless, it seems that spring data always loaded that `CGLIB` object.